# Visual Studio Code - tslint - pattern matcher

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I tried to implement the pattern matcher for tslint but it is going haywire. I am certain that regex is specified correctly, yet VSC keeps highlighting incorrect files. Here is my tasks.json file:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "gulp",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": [

],
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "args": [],
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        "problemMatcher": [
            {
                "owner": "gulp",
                "fileLocation": ["absolute"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^\\[[^>]* > ([^(]*)\\((\\d*),(\\d*)\\): (error) (.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "owner": "gulp",
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}/src/"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^\\([a-z\\-]*\\) ([^\\[]*)\\[([\\d]*), ([\\d]*)\\]: (.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 1,
                    "message": 4
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I am very interested in this as well. I had no idea VSC had the ability to do this. Has anyone who has setup code highlighting for vsc shed some light on this?

Comment: It has been corrected in 0.2.0 and works normally now. Look on the vs code web page for the description on how to add a new matcher (under tasks). You also need to understand regular expressions to do it.

Comment: been there, done that, but my matcher doesn't match anything... maybe you can help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055354/why-doesnt-this-problemmatcher-in-vs-code-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in version 0.2.0. It was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

No only do you have to understand regular expressions, but you have to remember to escape for json too!

To get this working from the straight output from `tslint` rather than the gulp version, I had to use:

`^(.*\.ts)\[(\d+), (\d+)\]: (.*)$`

In the json this becomes:

```
  "problemMatcher": {
    "owner": "tslint",
    "fileLocation": [
      "absolute"
    ],
    "severity": "warning",
    "pattern": {
      "regexp": "^(.*\\.ts)\\[(\\d+), (\\d+)\\]: (.*)$",
      "file": 1,
      "line": 2,
      "column": 3,
      "message": 4
    }
  }
```