# Why doesn't this problemMatcher in VS code work?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, gulp, tsify, vscode-problem-matcher

Why doesnt my problemMatcher work? I'm pretty sure about the regex, but it doesn't report any problems, even there are some on stdout...

```
// the matcher
"problemMatcher": {
    "owner": "typescript",
    "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
    "pattern": {
        "regexp": "^TypeScript (warning|error): (.*)\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\): (.*)$",
        "severity": 1,
        "file": 2,
        "line": 3,
        "column": 4,
        "message": 5
    }
}

//the browserify/tsify pipeline
browserify().add('main.ts')
  .plugin(tsify, { noImplicitAny: false, removeComments:true })
  .transform("babelify",{ extensions: ['.ts'], presets: ["es2015"]})
  .bundle()
  .on('error', function (error) { console.log(error.toString()); })
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www/js/dist/'));

//gulp sample output
[00:39:00] Starting 'ts-compile'...
TypeScript error: main.ts(118,30): Error TS2339: Property 'object' does not exist on type 'boolean'.
TypeScript error: main.ts(137,24): Error TS2339: Property 'object' does not exist on type 'boolean'.
TypeScript error: main.ts(507,44): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'loading'.
[00:39:03] Finished 'ts-compile' after 2.98 s
```

Comment: All regex libraries seem to differ in their details. If the regex is at fault, I'd suspect that the alternation operator `|` has higher precedence than expected. Try `((warning)|(error))` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @santa The regex works indeed. I'm able to get hree errors for the sample output in VSCode using your problem matcher. How does your tasks.json file look like?

Comment: already found my problem @Wosi i had to put the tasks.json into the .vscode folder (which contained a default which made me think that mine was used in the first place)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the problem by putting `tasks.json` into `.vscode` folder. I initially thought `tasks.json` would be found like `tsconfig.json` (project-root), but it turned out to be wrong.